# How to see remote commit history in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Its a shame but I can not figure out how to see remote commits history in VS Code.
I have a bunch of git related menu items, neither seems to be accomplish this task...

I would like to check it, because after I execute a push, I can not see any feedback if the push operation was successful or not... maybe this is too, my bad.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding git history, there's a bunch of VS Code addons that allows you see git log history e.g. `Git Graph`.

Yes, there is no explicit popup showing that push was successful, hence in order to check if push was successful you can check if local branch is paired with remote branch (if the HEAD commit after push is the latest for local and remote).

Small tip could be that, if there are no commits to push / to pull, the will be no numbers near the `synchronize changes` button in the bottom menu. Of course that tip will work only when VS Code is doing `git fetch` cyclically.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my (very limited) experience with this, Git and VS Code's implementation of Git follow the basic Unix process flow:

1. Silence is Golden:

   If you don't have anything interesting to say, keep quiet.
2. If you are going to fail, fail early and fail noisily.

In other words silence = success.
When something does go wrong, you absolutely know about it because it "makes a lot of noise" and provides copious terminal output.

VS Code provides a "panel" (usually located at the bottom) that can show a lot of different things, including git processing.

Note the following illustration:

[image: VS Code panel showing git output]

1. Make sure "output" is selected
2. Make sure the source is "git"
3. You have the git session output right there.  If anything wrong happened, this is where you'll see it.